# Let $f:K \to L$ a homomorphism of fields. Prove that $f$ induces a isomorphism of the prime fields of $K$ and $L$.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $f:K \to L$ a homomorphism of fields. Prove that $f$ induces a
>   isomorphism of the prime fields of $K$ and $L$.

Here are my thoughts:

Assume $K$ is infinite. Then $L$ must be infinite as well, since $f$ is injective. I know that the prime field of a infinite field is isomorphic with $\Bbb Q$. So them I'm done.

Assume $K$ is finite. Then I don't know what to do ?

Comment: It is not true that the prime field of an infinite field is necessarily $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: (1) There are infinite fields with finite prime field, e. g. $\mathbb F_2(X)$.

(2) Even if the two prime fields are isomorphic, this does not show that $f$ induces that isomorphism.

Comment: @Sebastian oh wait, this prime field can be finite even if the field is infinite

Comment: Well then I don't have any clue how to proof this. :P

Comment: You are on the right track: consider the composition $\mathbb{Z} \to K \overset{f}{\to} L$. What is the kernel of this composition?

Comment: @Sebastian I don't know if $\varphi:\Bbb Z \to K$ is injective or not. But if it is not injective, then the kernel of $f\circ \varphi$ is $(p)$. If it is injective, then it is $(0)$.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that every element of prime field of $k$, lets call it $P$, is of the form $1\frac nm$ because its the smallest subset of $k$ containing $1$ and $0$ closed on field operations. We know that $f(1)=1$ and $f(1\frac nm )=\frac nm f(1)$. This means that image of $f(P)$ is the prime field of $L$.

Comment: I've absolutely no clue where you are talking about.

Comment: Prime filed of $k$ is the smallest field contained in $k$. I has to contain $1$ so it contains elements $1+...+1=m1$. It is closed on division so so it has elements $1m/n$. And its easy to see that elements of this form are a subfield of $k$ and it have to be minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is injective we may view $K$ as a subfield of $L$. Then the prime field of $L$ must be $\subseteq K$ as otherwise its intersection with $K$ would be a smaller field. And as it has no proper subfields it must also be the prime field of $K$.